# Querystring security and dos attack

Tags: security, query-string

I've got an image generation servlet that generates an image text from a querystring and I use like this:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg.jsp?text=hello%20world">
```

**These below are my security measures:**

- Urlencoding of querystring parameter
- Domain whitelist
- Querystring parameter length check

**My questions:**

- Any security measure I'm forgetting there?
- How does the above increase DOS attack risks compared to a standard:

  ```
  <img src="myimage.jpg">
  ```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: URL has maximum limit of 1024 characters. Your URL including query string cannot be longer than 1024 bytes. What are the query parameters used for? If there are query parameters to control something like width or height of the generated image, someone can provide absurd values to make you run out of memory. All of this depends on how and what you do to generate images.

Comment: @Kal: You can reasonably distinguish between security *of* the API and security *behind* the API. Your height/width example is a clear case of the second. The "1024 char limit" (which doesn't actually exist) is security at the API level. I.e. allocating a 1024 char buffer for the URL and assuming it will fit is a security hole.

Comment: @MSalters I don't know if App / Web Servers support URL longer than 1024 bytes these days. I read the 1024 limit in the URL RFC few years ago. So, yes! it makes sense to not assume the 1024 limit and additionally validate the length of query string parameter anyway.

Comment: @Kal: That's (roughly speaking) a recommendation, as it tries to document the behavior of old systems not limit new systems. E.g. Internet Explorer has a 2048 character limit. And if you drop to TCP level, it's trivial to ignore any advice and send a megabyte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check would be,

1. Use HTTP Referer header to verify that requests are originated from your pages. This is only relevant if you are only going to use these images on pages of your site. You can verify that these images are loaded from your page and are not being directly included in page on some other site or the image URL is not directly accessed. This can easily be forged for performing a DOS attack though.
2. Check the underlying library you are using to generate the images. What parameters you are passing it for generating the image and check which parameters can potentially be controlled by user which can affect the size of image or processing time for the image. I am not sure how the font, font size are provided to the image, if they are hardcoded, or if they are derived through the information from the user.
3. Since this URL pattern generates an image, I am assuming every call is CPU intensive as well as includes some data transfer for the actual image. You may want to control the rate at which these URLs are fired, if you are really worried about DOS.
4. As I already mentioned in my comment, the URL can only be 1024 characters long, so there is inherent limit on number of characters that the text field can have. You can enforce a even smaller limit by providing an additional check.

Answer (score 0):

For DoS prevention rate limit how many requests can be received per IP per X number of seconds.

So to implement this, before doing any processing log the remote IP address of each request and then count the number of previous requests in the last e.g. 30 seconds. If the number from that IP address is greater than say 15 then reject the request with a "`HTTP 500.13 Web Server Too Busy`".

This is on the assumption that your database logging and lookup are less processor intensive than your image generation code. This will not protect against a large scale [DDoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack but it will reduce the risks considerably.

> Domain whitelist

I assume this is on the "`referer`" header? Yes, this would stop your image from being directly included in other websites but it could be circumvented by proxying the request via the other site's server. The DoS protection above would help alleviate this though.

`Querystring parameter length check`

Yes that would help reduce the amount of processing that a single image request could do.

> My questions:
>
> Any security measure I'm forgetting there?

Probably. As a start I would verify you are not at risk to the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10).

> How does the above increase DOS attack risks compared to a standard

A standard image request would simply request the static image off your server and the only real overhead would be IO. Processing though your JSP means that it is possible to overload your server by executing multiple requests at the same time as the CPU is doing a more work.